# Best practice of socket programming

Tags: flutter, websocket, socket.io

I'm dealing with a challenge and it's about what is the best practice for using a socket connection. I've developed an app that has 5 major parts and one of them is a chat(messaging) feature. I've used a socket connection for only this part. I've used this approach: I connect the socket channel whenever the user goes to the chat page and disconnect it whenever he changes his screen and leaves the chat page. Now my question is, is this (connecting and disconnecting) the best approach for using a socket connection? or it's better to leave the socket connection on from the begging of the app and never disconnect it even if the user is not using it and disconnect it only when the app is closed.

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think that only one websocket connection isn't going to increase badly the memory usage. The issue with your way of doing things is that you can't tell the user when a new message is comming through the websocket connection if the user isn't on the chat page. This might not be perfect. A good way of doing thing in your case might be to start websocket connection when the user is login and disconnect when user is logout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the receiving messages when the user is not on the chat page, I'm using push notifications, so this part is handled.

Comment: Oh ok, so I think there is no problem with your way of doing things